# Message posting PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, cookies

This runs fine with no errors and it is supposed to return comment from the logged in users friends. This code does not display any comments. My database has 4 fields; user1, user2, active, and id. User1 is the user who requests being a friend and user2 is the user that accepts it. Active is if the friendship is pending or "active". ID is the friendship id which starts at one and auto-increments. The id of the user is retrieved using a cookie. This is the code I have so far:

```
public function Updates($uid) 
{
    $host="localhost"; 
    $username="username"; 
    $password="password"; 
    $db_name="members"; 
    $tbl_name="friends";

    $user1=$_COOKIE["ID"];

    $link  = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot connect. Please contact us");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cannot select database. Please contact us");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user1 =$user1";
    $result=mysql_query($sql, $link) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());

    $query = mysql_query("
           SELECT
            M.msg_id,
            M.uid_fk, 
            M.message, 
            M.created,
            U.Firstname,
            U.Lastname
            FROM messages M
            JOIN users U ON U.UID = M.uid_fk
            JOIN friends F ON M.uid_fk = F.user2
            WHERE F.user1 = '$user1'
            ORDER BY M.created desc
        ") or die(mysql_error());
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
     $data[]=$row;
    return $data;
}
```

I hope this is enough to be able to understand what is going on. Help is much appreciated.

Table definitions:

[image: Database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
mysql_select_db("$db_name")
```

Should be:

```
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link)
```

And these lines don't do anything, since the $result is never used:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user1 =$user1";
$result=mysql_query($sql, $link) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
```

Lastly, `U.UID` should be `U.uid`. I'm pretty sure MySQL is case sensitive.

If you still have problems with your queries, run them directly in the MySQL Query Browser. It will help you debug your SQL.

I also think you should be careful about getting the user ID directly from a cookie. It's not hard to spoof a cookie, which will allow someone to gain direct access to someone else's account.

Comment: Very Helpful! Will take the cookie advice into strong consideration and will redesign this part of the project. Thanks Again!